# Sherrington-Kirkpatrick model with negative mean $J_0$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

In the Sherrington-Kirkpatrick (SK) model, one considers an Ising Hamiltonian

$$H = -\sum_{i<j}J_{ij}s_is_j$$

where $J_{ij}$ are drawn independently from a Gaussian distribution with mean $J_0$ and standard deviation $J$.

In their original papers [1,2], SK obtain the phase diagram:

[image]

I followed all the steps of the derivation. However I don't understand how the phase diagram for negative $J_0$ is derived, because there is a change of variables involved where the square root of $J_0$ is taken which would give an imaginary result (see line before Eq.(9) in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZjAY.png)). I think some (perhaps trivial) modifications are needed to obtain the phase diagram for negative $J_0$.

So my question is: Assuming replica symmetry (as SK), how does one derive the phase diagram for $J_0<0$?

**References**

1. https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.35.1792
2. https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.17.4384